# UIButton font Size Not Changing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am changing UIButton font size but it does not effect.

```
UIButton*headingButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

headingButton.frame=CGRectMake(182, 4, 450, 42);        

[headingButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:36/255.0 green:71/255.0 blue:113/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cant see in this code that u are changing font size but anyway, this can be done like so:

```
[headingButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:<your font name> size:<your desired size>]];
```

or

```
[headingButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:systemFontOfSize:<your desired size>]];
```

Update: plus you also need to see if the font u are setting exists in your app to check just do this:

```
NSLog(@"Font family names: %@", [UIFont familyNames]);
NSLog(@"Fonts in family Myriad Pro : %@", [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Myriad Pro"]);
```

If it doesnt exist, you need to drag the otf file into ur project and also add the "Fonts provided by application" in info.plist

Comment: [headingButton.titleLabel.setFont =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Myriad Pro Bold" size:24]];

Comment: thats not the correct format. Use [headingButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Myriad Pro Bold" size:24]]; if this is not ur problem see my edit

Comment: i this might be this font name not available in ios because when i am given font name Arial its working

Answer (score 0):

```
 btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:8.0];

 btn.titleLabel.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:btn.titleLabel.font.pointSize+3];
```

first Line for set font name and size and second line for bold a font